# Can java SSLException: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify be safely ignored?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, mysql-connector

I'm connecting to a MySQL 5.7 server from a java 1.8 app using the [MySQL Connector/J 5.1.47 (2018-08-17)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/5.1/en/news-5-1-47.html). I know this an old version of the libary, but I need to use it because I need to also connect to a MySQL 5.5 database from the same java app, and this is the last version that I'm aware of that supports 5.5 and 5.7. I have no problems connecting to both databases, but when I try to close either of the connections, I get the following error printed to my log:

```
Wed Aug 25 10:48:03 IST 2021 WARN: Caught while disconnecting...

EXCEPTION STACK TRACE:

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

javax.net.ssl.SSLException
MESSAGE: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify

STACKTRACE:

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: closing inbound before receiving peer's close_notify
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:726)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.shutdownInput(SSLSocketImpl.java:705)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.quit(MysqlIO.java:2249)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.realClose(ConnectionImpl.java:4232)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.close(ConnectionImpl.java:1472)
    at ie.myapp.Database.closeConnection(Database.java:115)

** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
```

Note that there is no exception being thrown here. This warning is being printed somewhere along the line in the `java.sql.Connection.close()` call.  There are references to this error around, but a common suggestion I've come across is to disable SSL on the connection (which I cannot/will not do).

In any case, based on [this conversation regarding a pull request for the MySQL connector library](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/pull/32), my understanding is that the warning was suppressed or dropped from later versions of the library, which suggests that the warning is harmless?

Also, I've written some tests to confirm that after closing connections to my databases, the database does actually have no record of the users/sessions e.g. `select id, user... from information_schema.processlist` as a rough check that there's no resource leak on the DB.

So, my question is: can anyone that understands this warning (or has an understanding of what might give rise to this warning) advise me if ignoring it will have any side effects? (other than filling my logs with that warning).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this was an issue with the MySQL driver on Java 11. This has been fixed in Connector/J version 8.0.16. This SSLException log was not coming after this upgrade.
Reference for bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=93590